# MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file... That may also mean that you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pythonanywhere, moviepy

When I run a python telegram bot script locally, it works completely fine but when I run the script on `PythonAnywhere` I get an error that shows up when I try to generate a video:

```
"2023-08-29 15:21:53,138 (__init__.py:960 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file /home/AlisterK/video_clips/Video 2023-01-10 
18 45 07.mp4. That might mean that the file is corrupted. That may also mean that you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG. On Ubuntu/Debian for instance the version in the repos is deprecated. Pleas
e update to a recent version from the website."
2023-08-29 15:21:53,138 (__init__.py:962 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 955, in infinity_polling
    self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 6788, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "/home/AlisterK/Video generator.py", line 34, in generate_video_command
    generated_video = generate_video(audio_files[user_id])
  File "/home/AlisterK/Video generator.py", line 72, in generate_video
    clips = [VideoFileClip(os.path.join(input_folder, clip_file)).subclip(0, clip_duration) for clip_file in video_clips]
  File "/home/AlisterK/Video generator.py", line 72, in <listcomp>
    clips = [VideoFileClip(os.path.join(input_folder, clip_file)).subclip(0, clip_duration) for clip_file in video_clips]
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.lastread = self.read_frame()
  File "/home/AlisterK/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py", line 133, in read_frame
    raise IOError(("MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of "
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file /home/AlisterK/video_clips/Video 2023-01-10 18 45 07.mp4. That might mean that the file is corrupted. That may also mean that you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG. On Ubuntu/Debian for instance the version in the repos is deprecated. Please update to a recent version from the website."
```

I tried updating ffmpeg and moviepy. I even tried different versions but to no avail. The video clips are not corrupted as I checked.

This part of the code is responsible for generating the videos:

```py
def generate_video(audio_path):
    input_folder = '/home/AlisterK/video_clips'  # Replace with your folder path
    output_file = '/home/AlisterK/output_combined_video.mp4'
    clip_duration = 3  # Duration of each clip in seconds
    num_clips = 10     # Number of video clips to select and combine

    width = 1080  # Replace with your desired width
    height = 1920  # Replace with your desired height

    video_clips = random_files_in_folder(input_folder, '.mp4', num_clips)

    clips = [VideoFileClip(os.path.join(input_folder, clip_file)).subclip(0, clip_duration) for clip_file in video_clips]
    standardized_clips = [clip.resize((width, height)) for clip in clips]  # Ensure consistent resolutions

    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(standardized_clips)

    final_audio = AudioFileClip(audio_path)
```

Comment: If moviepy will not work with the Ubuntu version of ffmpeg, then it will probably not work on PythonAnywhere because it is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: What version of moviepy and ffmpeg do you have on PythonAnywhere? Have you checked the moviepy docs where they say how to set a custom ffmpeg path? If you can install the latest ffmpeg, I think it's 6.0 now, and set its path for moviepy, check again your script. Basically you would only need something like `VideoFileClip('test.mp4')` to check if it loads a file as the error is thrown in the constructor.

Comment: @mortalis I can't install a newer version of ffmpeg. ffmpeg version = 4.2.7. Moviepy version = 2.0.0.dev2

Comment: You said you tried updating ffmpeg and moviepy. What't the result of that? How do you update ffmpeg on that env, does it have apt or some package manager?

Comment: @mortalis It has like pre-installed packages and they only go up to a certain version

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/10941. If you can execute wget, tar, make, you could try building ffmpeg from source. But it's interesting if the versions for ffmpeg and moviepy you've mentioned earlier give the same error on your local env.

Comment: @mortalis when I try to install the ffmpeg myself from the website it says this: wget http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
--2023-09-01 23:47:16--  http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
Resolving proxy.server (proxy.server)... 10.0.0.118
Connecting to proxy.server (proxy.server)|10.0.0.118|:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2023-09-01 23:47:16 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: That would be an issue for the forum I think. Also I see a post regarding 403 on that page. Something about permissions maybe. The principle is that you have to copy those files to the env, maybe there's a way PythonAnywhere provides to copy external files, or check if they have ssh and with WinSCP for example you can access the file system. Or upload them to a place from where wget will work. Basically for yasm I would try installing it with apt first, maybe its version would be enough for building ffmpeg.